# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed in shopizer

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, shopizer

After following the instruction of buildin Shopizer from this link
https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer

and after building and moving sm-shop.war to Tomcat webapps folder and then accessing the url:
http://localhost:8080/sm-shop/shop

I'm facing this error

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

So, what is the problem, can anybody help ?

Comment: sounds like invalid jndi name for jpa context, as it's tomcat, let say if the database pool name is `jdbc/my_db`, in jpa context it should be pointed as `java:/comp/env/jdbc/my_db`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It expects [this DB configuration](https://github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer/blob/e509b492185d59ba06b6a74197448ed9b31189ee/shopizer/sm-shop/src/main/resources/database.properties).

You have two options:

1. Configure your own local DB and fill it with your connection and authentication details (config is using MySQL).
2. Uncomment H2 database config and comment out MySQL config. H2 is embedded database and therefore you wouldn't need to install anything.

Comment: Thank you so much, I followed the second option and it works !

Comment: it shows me empty content, only the search bar appear, it there anyway to load sample data ?

Comment: H2 database is presumably empty, therefore you don't get any data. I would google if there is some initial schema script for Shopizer. If you don't find anything, I would create Github issue.

Comment: I'll be waiting for your solution, sample data is necessary to test shopizer functionality, thanks